# Azure devops need to access Azure keyvault which is restrict to private link

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

If I would like to read the key in Azure keyvault (which is restricted to access from private endpoint only ) from Azure devops build/release pipeline , what I should do ?

if I have a deployment agent host (Azure VM) in my own subscription , and whitelist the IP addresss of this VM to Azure keyvault can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the key vault with private endpoint, you do not have to configure Key vault firewall for that. See the statement from Microsoft docs

> The private links feature doesn't require any "virtual network" to be specified in the key vault firewall settings. All requests using the private IP address of the key vault (see next section) must work, even if no virtual network is specified in key vault firewall settings.
> The private links feature doesn't require specifying any IP address in the key vault firewall settings. Again, all requests using the private IP address of the key vault must work, even if no IP address was specified in the firewall settings.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal)
All you need to do that should host vm and keyvault withing same subnet/vnet or if you host them into different vnets you need to make sure vnet peering were configured. Also if you use make sure nsg/firewall is not preventing connection between subnet/vnet.

Comment: my point is for azure devops to take a secret , for example a azure sql database password , which is inside a keyvault , and this keyvault is behind private endpoint . how to do that?

Comment: There is no term as behind a private endpoint. Private endpoints are just one of the access methods in network layer. So basically what you can do is that if these agent and key vault resides in different vnet basically you can allow connection from agent vnet via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security#key-vault-firewall-enabled-virtual-networks---dynamic-ips . And with that way you do not have to use private endpoints you will allow connection to key vault from allowed vnet which is agent vnet in your case.